# How can I maximise orthonormality between degenerate eigenvectors using ARPACK?

Tags: eigensystem, arpack

I am using ARPACK's zndrv1 to diagonalise a matrix (the context is quantum chemistry). While all vectors have a norm 1, as expected, vectors corresponding to degenerate eigenstates aren't always orthogonal (often their inner product will be roughly 0.01).

Are there any parameters I can adjust to improve orthonormality (even if it means longer compute time)?

I understand there are alternative libraries and routines out there. I am specifically curious about ARPACK.

Comment: Are these vectors orthogonal with the non-degenerate ones?

Comment: Yes. Their inner product is typically on the order of magnitude of 1e-8 to 1e-13, which is more than enough accuracy for my purposes.

Comment: What happens if you orthogonalize (e.g. by Modified Gram-Schmidt) the vectors that you've gotten from ARPACK associated with the null eigenvalues?  Are the resulting eigenvectors usable?